# How to do a good code review in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I have used a few code review programs.  I am now using pull requests in Bitbucket.  I am expecting a certain process:

1. Create review (ie pull request)
2. Comments are added by reviewers.  ( am used to a graded system where someone can mark the change as a bug which needs to be fixed before being merged)
3. The review is sent back to the originator who fixes any problems that are marked
4. (!!)The originator pushes their changes to their branch and then the code review is done again by all reviewers who then approve or reject the new changes.
5. With all things being good, the review is approved and then merged.

What I am wondering about are steps 3 and 4.  There seems no grading to the comments and there seems to be no way for the originator to see quickly the comments (in some condensed format).  Also, how do new changes update a pull request?  Is this just missing from the Bitbucket system or is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- "*there seems to be no way for the originator to see quickly the comments (in some condensed format)*".  Open a pull request, and look over on the right hand side.  I see 3 tabs: Details / Files / Activity.  Under "Activity", I can filter to "All Comments".
- "*how do new changes update a pull request?*"  When creating a pull request, you are requesting approval from your colleagues to pull code from some source branch to some target branch.  So, when the source branch is updated with changes, the pull request should automatically reflect that.  In other words, you shouldn't have to take any extra action.

Answer (score 0):

- "*There seems no grading to the comments*" A reviewer can check a box that says "merge not allowed until the 'issue fixed' box is checked." The repo admin has some latitude to set how strict the PR / merge policies will be, including whether approval is needed from anyone or from specific individuals.